# JS: Why (![]+[])[+[]] returns "f"?

Tags: javascript

If you try to run following code you will see that
`(![]+[])[+1]` returns "a";
`(![]+[])[+2]` returns "l";
`(![]+[])[+3]` returns "s".
And so on.
Why?

Comment: Have you *at least* tried looking at what the individual parts of those expressions evaluate to?

Comment: (![]+[]) is "false" => (![]+[])[+2] is "l", not "1" (one).

Comment: `(![]+[])` evaluates to `"false"` and then you are simply accessing the characters of the string as an array. The reason why is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(![]+[])` returns `"false"` in javascript. The `+1` takes the letter at index `1`. Therefore `a`.

Comment: `(![]+[])` returns the string `"false"` and not the boolean value, just to make things clear.

Answer (score 10):

Let's break it down piece by piece.

```
> ![]
false
```

Array literals are truthy even when empty, so the negation is boolean false.

```
> ![]+[]
"false"
```

Adding a boolean (the false from above) to an empty array results in the string version of `"false"`, thanks to JS's strange rules for adding arbitrary objects.

```
> (![]+[])[1]
"a"
> (![]+[])[3]
"s"
(etc)
```

is equivalent to:

```
> "false"[1]
"a"
> "false"[3]
"s"
```

and so on -- indexing a string returns the character at that index.

Finally,

```
> +[]
0
```

so

```
> "false"[+[]]
"f"
```

and putting it all together:

```
> (![]+[])[+[]]
"f"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're indexing the result of the first expression as a string.

(![]+[]) => false

false[1] => "false"[1] => a

Comment: `(![]+[])` returns the string false. `false[1]` returns `undefined`, there is no conversion to string that would happen.